# List Validation Settings

Tags: list, validation

I am trying to create a list validation rule that works for more than 1 argument. I have 2 dates as input, DATE1 AND DATE2, and a third date which is used to check that the first 2 have not expired, DATE3. I can get this to work for one condition using =[DATE1]>[DATE3] but I can't seem to find the syntax for multiple conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `=AND(Expr1,Expr2)`

```
=AND(DATE1>DATE3,DATE2>DATE3)
```

PS: Depending on localization, the separator could be `;` not `,`